# onmouseover expand image sides to left and right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to expand the left and right side of an image.For example if a image size is 1100px width then partial left and right will be expanded.I don't want to do full image expansion.

```
<div class="side_left"></div>
<div class="mid_container"></div>
<div class="side_right"></div>
```

**Here you can see my code:**       http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/EgHGm/

Comment: Are you doing the expansion on hover as in the fiddle?  Cuz that doesn't require any script at all, just some good old-fashioned CSS.

Comment: yes on hover the image will be expanded to its full width but I don't want to change the width from xxx to yyy.if you see the fiddle then mid part is not expanding only left and right part is moving.I want the same but without using div as z-index.I am not sure if it can be done with pure css or jquery.

Comment: I'm confused - what is wrong with the example you posted?

Comment: Evan I don't want to use side_left and side_right divs.Without using these 2 divs can I achieve the same output as now? Sorry if it sounds confusing still.Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hLMTW/

```
.mid_container {
    background: url(http://www.jeffreyhomesinc.com/images/banner%202.png) -35px 0 no-repeat;
    height: 245px;
    margin: auto 35px;
    width: 1030px;
    float:left;
}

.mid_container:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1100px;
}
```

If you'd prefer to animate the transition, you can use CSS animation:

```
.mid_container:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1100px;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slide;
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        background-position: -35px 0;
        margin: 0 35px;
        width: 1030px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 1100px;
    }
}
```

The caveat of course is that the hover effect won't work at all on downlevel browsers, though it is supported by all the main browsers in their latest versions.  You can expand support for the effect somewhat by duplicating it with -moz and -webkit prefixes.  This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hLMTW/5/) includes the backward-compatibility prefixes.

Please accept the answer if it resolves your question.

Comment: Both sides are moving.  Please ensure your window is wide enough to see the right side.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a ton. I have never thought about this idea.Now is it possible to add sort of animation to it?

Comment: Excellent..close enough.Thanks.just a small thing ie when I mouseover it expands which is good but after 3 secs it's coming back to the previous state.Can we add mouseover and mouseout so that when I mouseover the animation continues and when i mouseout then it will come back to 1030px.

Comment: oops, somehow i lost part of it.  restored.  it should now expand permanently in all browsers and animate that expansion in all browsers that support CSS animation.

Comment: Thanks.I am using FF and while expanding I can see the animation but after 3 secs it's going back to previous state.Is there any way to add mouseout in css or I have to use jquery?

Comment: It's no longer jumping back after three seconds.

Comment: Thank a lot.Yes it is not jumping back after 3s.In FF it's perfect.In chrome when mouseover the animation is not so smooth like FF.

Answer (score 0):

in your css, you put

```
background-position: "center center";
```

. It will center your background image to the center

what left is just expand the div out
http://jsfiddle.net/EgHGm/1/

center the div in the middle and it should be fine

Comment: Thanks Mun for your effort but this is not what I want.If you go through the output then I want exact same result but without using side_left and side_right divs.

Comment: please check the fiddle again... there's only 1 div... http://jsfiddle.net/EgHGm/1/